# recursive method in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, methods, vue.js, vue-component

I am attempting to call a method within itself in Vue, however I'm getting the following error

> this.loop is not a function. (In 'this.loop()', 'this.stagger'
>   is undefined)

here is the method:

```
    loop: function () {
            var n = $(".item").length;
            var i = 1;
            var m = n + 5;
          setTimeout( function () {
                $('.item:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('show');
                var x = i - 2;
                var y = x - 2;
                i = i + 3;

                // for 2 columns:
                // x = i - 1;
                // i = i + 2;

                $('.item:nth-child('+x+')').addClass('show');
                $('.item:nth-child('+y+')').addClass('show'); // remove for 2 columns


            if (i < m) {
                this.loop() // error occurs here
            }
          }, 100)
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because `this` no longer refers to the object when in the callback function of `setTimeout`. There are several solutions.

You could change the `function` to an arrow function:

```
setTimeout( () => {
```

That way `this` will retain its original value, also within the callback.

Or, you could bind `this` to the function:

```
setTimeout( function () {
    // ...
}.bind(this), 100)
//^^^^
```

Or, you could copy `this`and use that instead:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout( function () {
    // ...
    that.loop();
    // ...
}, 100)
```

#### Avoiding reinitialisation

Currently your recursive calls will also reset the variables, including `i`.

Solve this, by passing `i` as argument:

```
loop: function (i = 1) { // <<---- default value
    var n = $(".item").length;
    var m = n + 5;
    if (i >= m) return; // <<-----
    setTimeout(() => {
        $('.item:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('show');
        var x = i - 2;
        var y = x - 2;
        $('.item:nth-child('+x+')').addClass('show');
        $('.item:nth-child('+y+')').addClass('show');
        this.loop(i+3); // <<------
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: yes that seemed to do away with the error, being that you solved the question within the scope i approved it. However would you mind if i ask a question outside the scope of this answer?

Comment: You can always hit the "Ask Question" button again. But be sure to check if it has not been asked before.

Comment: i need to declare the first three variables within the above function: `var n = $(".item").length;
            var i = 1;
            var m = n + 5;` , outside of the function, globally , because it seems this is stopping the method from running accordingly

Comment: any suggestions how to go about doing so?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: your an awesome individual!